# The Activiti site is lost css?

Tags: activiti

When I visiting the Activiti site 'https://www.activiti.org/', it can't display correctly, the layout is not correct and lost its style, and I tried to ask somebody to visit this site, and it's same to me, what is the problem?

Comment: Looks ok to me. Try a ctrl-f5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, the Lantern caused the issue.